# Assign VBA code for a button to run off of workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a workbook with an object button that I've created called "Create New User". I've assigned the macro from "This Workbook" called "`createnewuser`".

However, if I send the workbook to someone and/or I create a copy of the workbook the button fails when clicked as it's looking for the file-path based on my NTID/etc.

How can I set the macro(s) so that they run based off of the workbook and not based off of my NTID/file-path/etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this property:

[`Workbook.Path` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff840974.aspx) like this: `ActiveWorkbook.Path`

> Returns a `String` that represents the complete path to the workbook/file that this workbook object represents.